# What size surface hinges are required for utility sized cabinet doors?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

What size surface hinges are required for utility sized cabinet doors?  What about the number of hinges?

Does a formula or chart exist to help me figure it out?  Want to make sure I don't have too much unsupported weight.

Sizes of "utility" doors:

1. L 47 3/4" x W 24" x D 3/4"
2. L 53" X W 44 3/4" X D 3/4"
3. L 22" X W 17 3/4" X D 13/16"

Comment: How about a picture of the cabinet, or the doors.

Comment: Size and thickness of the door would be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't *exactly* answer your question, but look at this article, particularly the chart at the bottom: https://www.rockler.com/how-to/choose-right-blum-hinge-cabinet-doors/

Comment: @EdBeal I got the measurements listed.

Comment: @JACK  I listed the measurements

Comment: Mike gave a good link for hidden hinges,+  number 1 & 3 could probably do it with a couple of 2” but number 3 that is a heavy door probably 4” rack or multiples like the link mike provided. The look will be the next question , a utility room you may not care about and barn door hinges will be ok, if you want hidden again look at the link mike provided.